# calculate totals without $watch and <input max="null when 0 else value"/>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, max, watch

I have a working prototype for my computational program. http://plnkr.co/edit/U2uwWkvm6S62bfO0RBEw

I would like to be able to calculate the totals without the `$watch`. Change the Fuel amount and you can see the others change accordingly.

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to bind the `max=""` in the `<input>` tag to allow "null" when `Maximum == 0` else use the `Maximum` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the total field (totalWeight, totalMoment and CG) to a scope function.

**Index.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped">

    ..........

    <tr>
      <td colspan=4 class="text-right" style="font-weight: bold;">Totals:</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{calculator.getTotalWeight() | number:0}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right">{{calculator.getTotalMoment() | number:0}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=5 class="text-right" style="font-weight: bold;">CG:</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{calculator.getTotalMoment()/calculator.getTotalWeight() | number:2}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**app.js**

```
var WtBalApp = angular.module('wtBalApp', []);

WtBalApp.controller('WtBalController', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.positions = [{
    Station: 'Empty Weight',
    Quantity: 1345,
    Max: 2300,
    Arm: 35.6,
    Mult: 1,
    ReadOnly: true,
    Consumable: false
  }, {
    Station: 'Pilot',
    Quantity: 0,
    Max: 0,
    Arm: 34,
    Mult: 1,
    ReadOnly: false,
    Consumable: false
  }, {
    Station: 'Front Passenger',
    Quantity: 0,
    Max: 0,
    Arm: 34,
    Mult: 1,
    ReadOnly: false,
    Consumable: false
  }, {
    Station: 'Fuel',
    Quantity: 50,
    Max: 50,
    Arm: 36,
    Mult: 6,
    ReadOnly: false,
    Consumable: true
  }, {
    Station: 'Rear Passenger #1',
    Quantity: 0,
    Max: 0,
    Arm: 34,
    Mult: 1,
    ReadOnly: false,
    Consumable: false
  }, {
    Station: 'Rear Passenger #2',
    Quantity: 0,
    Max: 0,
    Arm: 34,
    Mult: 1,
    ReadOnly: false,
    Consumable: false
  }];
$scope.calculator = {
    getTotalWeight: function(){
      var totalWeight=0;
      $scope.positions.forEach(function(position) {
        totalWeight += position.Quantity * position.Mult;
      });
      return totalWeight;
    },
    getTotalMoment: function(){
      var totalMoment=0;
      $scope.positions.forEach(function(position) {
        totalMoment += position.Quantity * position.Mult * position.Arm;
      });
      return totalMoment;
    } 
}
});
```

And use this conditional statement to bind the max attribute to null when maximum value == 0

```
max="{{position.Max===0?'':position.Max}}"
```

Here is the [Plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wZHJQGCcP6MRcCIVvUvK?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change the $watch to a function on the scope

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function() {
...
```

And then call this function each time the input value changes by adding `ng-change="calculateTotal()"` to your input box.

To display the values when the page loads, call `$scope.calculateTotal();` at the bottom of your controller.

Here's the [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dtSp4WyUf0bkWyCh38xO?p=preview)